# java.lang.NullPointerException in android database activity

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm new in Android and I am creating an application. But my I am receiving an error through logcat which says

```
03-16 09:11:52.372: E/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 09:11:52.372: E/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutbuddy/com.example.workoutbuddy.DatabaseAddClient}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any suggestions on what should I do? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

**XML file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Full Name:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fullname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGender"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Gender" />

  <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id ="@+id/gender">
         <RadioButton android:id="@+id/genderMale"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Male"
                 />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/genderFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Age" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/age_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Address" />

    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/address_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactNum"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Contact No." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactNum_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Height (cm)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Weight (kg)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
       />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWorkoutType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Choose type of workout plan:" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/workout_type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWorkoutDay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Choose workout days:" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/workout_day"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" 
        android:onClick = "workout_type"/>

</LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

**Java file**

```
package com.example.workoutbuddy;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast; 
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DatabaseAddClient extends Activity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ClientDBHelper dh;

private EditText fullname;
private EditText address_client;
private RadioGroup gender;
private RadioButton tbxClientGender;
private EditText contactNum_client;
private EditText height_client;
private EditText weight_client;
private EditText age_client;

private Button btnSaveCustomer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addclient);

    fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);

    gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    tbxClientGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

    age_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_client);
    address_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address_client);
    contactNum_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactNum_client);
    height_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_client);
    weight_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_client);
    dh = new ClientDBHelper(this);

   btnSaveCustomer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //edited portion starts here----    
        String heightString = height_client.getText().toString();
            final double heightDouble = Double.parseDouble(heightString);

            String weightString = weight_client.getText().toString();
            final double weightDouble = Double.parseDouble(heightString);

            final double body_mass = heightDouble / weightDouble;

            String status = null;

            if (body_mass < 18.5){
                status = "UNDERWEIGHT";
            } else if (body_mass == 18.5 && body_mass <=24.9){
                status = "NORMAL";
            }else if (body_mass == 25 && body_mass <=29.9){
                status = "OVERWEIGHT";
            }else if (body_mass >=30){
                status = "OBESE";
            }

            final String finalStatus = status;
        // ---- edited portion ends here

            if (fullname.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Name is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fullname.requestFocus();

            } else if (age_client.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Age is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                age_client.requestFocus();

            } else if (address_client.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Address is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                address_client.requestFocus();

            } else if (contactNum_client.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Contact number is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                contactNum_client.requestFocus();

            } else if (height_client.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Height is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                height_client.requestFocus();

            } else if (weight_client.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Weight is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                weight_client.requestFocus();

            } else {
                ProgressDialog progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DatabaseAddClient.this, 
                     "Saving Customer", "Saving customer to database...", true);



                String new_client_fullname = fullname.getText().toString();
                String new_client_age = age_client.getText().toString();
                String new_client_address = address_client.getText().toString();
                String new_client_contactnumber = contactNum_client.getText().toString();
                String new_client_height = height_client.getText().toString();
                String new_client_weight = weight_client.getText().toString();
                String new_client_gender = tbxClientGender.getText().toString();
                String new_client_bmi = String.valueOf(body_mass);
    String new_client_status = String.valueOf(finalStatus);



                db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.FULLNAME, new_client_fullname);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.GENDER, new_client_gender);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.AGE, new_client_age);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.ADDRESS, new_client_address);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.CONTACT_NUM, new_client_contactnumber);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.HEIGHT, new_client_height);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.WEIGHT, new_client_weight);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.BMI, new_client_bmi);
                values.put(ClientDBHelper.STATUS, finalStatus);


                db.insert(ClientDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                db.close();

                progDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(DatabaseAddClient.this, "Customer " 
                        + new_client_fullname + " has been added successfully", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.workoutbuddy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.workoutbuddy.DatabaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.workoutbuddy.DatabaseAddClient"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.workoutbuddy.DatabaseEditClient"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.workoutbuddy.DatabaseViewClient"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.example.workoutbuddy.OwnCalendar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: NPE is easy to find: go to the line printed in the stack trace and look at references.  Or run your code in a debugger, stepping through until you find what's null.

Comment: If you can't find what's `null` then please post the full stacktrace so we can help you. It is way too difficult to go through someone's code to see what "might" be `null`

Comment: Also, this is normally a little much code when first asking. Its very good that you added code since many don't at all. But it is helpful for other members if you can narrow down about where the problem is or may be and post the code that you think is relevant along with errors and full stacktrace then edit and post more if people ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `btnSaveCustomer` is not initialized before usage. You should do something like

```
btnSaveCustomer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
```

before calling

```
btnSaveCustomer.setOnClickListener();
```